# Get column name of excel sheet

Tags: c#, .net, excel, oledb

I want to retrieve the name of the excel column in C#.Net.
I get all the other information except the column names.

My excel file looks like this:

```
#|     A    |      B      |

1|   NAME   |   Address   |

2|   chris  |  xx street  |
```

Here is my code:

I think "name" is save like title in my file and OleDb don't get it .
How can i resolve my problem?

Comment: Besides your specific point, note that you are creating a new `LigneXls` object with each `Read`. You may have memory leaks.

Comment: Perhaps advancing with one `Read` prior to starting your loop?